# SwiftUI memory leak when using UIViewControllerRepresentable

Tags: swiftui

***UPDATE: As of beta4, problem still present.***

I have created a very simple example of how a UIViewController represented by UIViewControllerRepresentable is **never** deallocated.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var showRepView = true

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Square").font(.largeTitle).tapAction {
                self.showRepView.toggle()
            }

            if showRepView {
                SomeRepView().frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The representation implementation follows:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct SomeRepView: View {
    var body: some View {
        RepViewController()
    }
}

struct RepViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable
{
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> SomeCustomeUIViewController {
        let vc =  SomeCustomeUIViewController()
        print("INIT \(vc)")
        return vc
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: SomeCustomeUIViewController, context: Context) {
    }

    static func dismantleUIViewController(_ uiViewController: SomeCustomeUIViewController, coordinator: Self.Coordinator) {
        print("DISMANTLE")
    }

}

class SomeCustomeUIViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        print("viewWillDissapear \(self)")
    }

    deinit {
        print("DEINIT \(self)")
    }

}
```

By tapping on the "Square" button, `SomeRepView` is added and removed alternatively. However, the related UIViewController is never released. That can be seen by the logged messages and I also confirmed with Instruments.

Note that SomeRepView is released properly. It is only the corresponding view controller what remains allocated.

Also note that the `UIViewController.viewWillDissappear` is called and also the `UIViewControllerRepresentable.dismantleUIViewController`

This is a typical output of pressing the Square button repeatedly.

```
INIT <SomeCustomeUIViewController: 0x100b1af70>
DISMANTLE
viewWillDissapear <SomeCustomeUIViewController: 0x100b1af70>
INIT <SomeCustomeUIViewController: 0x100a0a8c0>
DISMANTLE
viewWillDissapear <SomeCustomeUIViewController: 0x100a0a8c0>
INIT <SomeCustomeUIViewController: 0x100b23690>
DISMANTLE
viewWillDissapear <SomeCustomeUIViewController: 0x100b23690>
```

As show, `DEINIT` is never printed.

My question is... is it a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

Running with iOS13, beta 4.

I tried triggering **Simulate Memory Warning**. No effect. The controllers persist. Instruments is my witness ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Xcode 11, beta 5, bug was patched.

Comment: Sorry to say but this still remains in Xcode 12.5

Comment: Happening for us in Xcode 13