# SwiftUI memory leak when using NavigationLink Push UIViewControllerRepresentable?

Tags: swiftui

This situation is no problem.[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56699009/swiftui-memory-leak-when-using-uiviewcontrollerrepresentable)

So I'm confused, I don't know if this is a bug or whether Apple designed it this way.

```
struct HomePage: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                jumpView1
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .padding()
                jumpView2
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.blue)
            }
            .navigationBarItems(leading:leftBarItem)
            .navigationBarTitle("Home",displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
    var leftBarItem: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: CustomViewController()) {
               Text("Go CustomViewController ")
           }
    }
    var jumpView1: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: CustomViewController()) {
                       Text("Go CustomViewController")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
    }
    var jumpView2: some View {
           NavigationLink(destination: SecondPage()) {
                          Text("Go SecondPage")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
           }
    }
}
```

```
struct FirstPage: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: CustomViewController()) {
                       Text("Go CustomViewController")
        }
    }
}
struct SecondPage: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: CustomViewController()) {
                       Text("Go CustomViewController")
        }
    }
}
```

the func dismantleUIViewController only call in leftBarItem Action,
and never call, when push in body NavigatinLink

```
struct CustomViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) ->  CustomRealViewController {
        let vc = CustomRealViewController()
        return vc
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: CustomRealViewController, context: Context) {
    }

    static func dismantleUIViewController(_ uiViewController: CustomRealViewController, coordinator: Coordinator) {
        print("dismiss")
        
    }
    
}
```

the func deinit only call in leftBarItem Action,
and never call, when push in body NavigatinLink

```
class CustomRealViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        print("viewDidDisappear")
    }
    deinit {
        print("deinit")
    }
}
```