# UIViewControllerRepresentable causes memory leak when in NavigationView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory-leaks, swiftui

I'm aware about [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56699009/swiftui-memory-leak-when-using-uiviewcontrollerrepresentable) that `UIViewControllerRepresentable` could cause a memory leak. Even if it should be fixed with past Xcode releases, I'm facing it only when embedding it in a `NavigationView`. I'm using Xcode Version 11.7 (11E801a) on a physical iPhone 11 iOS 13.7

Here an example:

Memory leak

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {   // Memory leak
            ZStack {
                Text("Hello, World!")
                ViewControllerContainer() // Memory leak
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


struct ViewControllerContainer: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        return UIViewController()
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

No memory leak

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text("Hello, World!")
            ViewControllerContainer() // No memory leak
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


struct ViewControllerContainer: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        return UIViewController()
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

Is it a xcode/swiftui related bug or I missing something?

**EDIT**:
Screenshot of Instruments/Leaks
[image]

**UPDATE**:

The leak is not showing up with iPhone 11 (iOS 13.7) simulator

Comment: How did you detect it? Instruments/Leaks does not show any leak for your code. Xcode 11.7 / iOS 13.7.

Comment: Hi @Asperi, exactly with Instruments/Leaks. See edit

Comment: I find the exact same leak with my full project. The code above comes from a new ad hoc project

Comment: Is happening to me the exact same behavior in a NavigationView/Link