# having a memory leak when implementing a image picker in SwiftUI using UIViewControllerRepresentable

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to get the user to pick an image from their gallery. After doing some research I was able to accomplish this task by using a UIViewControllerRepresentable. However, after I opened up the memory debugger it shows that I have a memory leak

I created a basic example to which would make the code a lot simpler to read and still address the same issue without copy-pasting my entire code. the code below also shows a memory leak

```
// code for the views

import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(
                destination: ImagePickerView(),
                label: {
                    Text("Navigate")
                })
        }
    }
}

struct ImagePickerView: View {
    
    @State var image = UIImage()
    @State var showController: Bool = false
    @State var didChoose : Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            showController = true
        }, label: {
            Text("pick image")
        })
        .sheet(isPresented: $showController, content: {
            ImagePicker(image: $image, didChoose: $didChoose)
        })
    }
}
```

```
struct ImagePicker : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var image: UIImage
    @Binding var didChoose: Bool
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIViewController {
        let controller = UIImagePickerController()
        controller.delegate = context.coordinator
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ImagePicker.UIViewControllerType, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {
        
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator : NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
        
        
        let parent : ImagePicker
        init(_ parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            
            guard let pickedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
                print("could not unwrap the image")
                return
            }
            print(pickedImage)
            self.parent.image = pickedImage
            self.parent.didChoose = true
            self.parent.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect the cause to be the in the coordinator class however, ifailed to identify the reason behind it. is it involved with the parent?

Comment: What exactly does the memory debugger show? Can you post a screenshot of the graph with the relationships?

Comment: It seems to be a general bug for `UIViewControllerRepresentable` https://stackoverflow.com/q/56699009/1049134