# StateObject doesn't deinit when PhotosPicker was presented

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, environmentobject

I just do some experiments in my pet project on iOS 16 Beta. I noticed one possible memory leak. I created a simple project with simple steps which reproduce this behavior. So I have `ContentView` and `DetailView` I use `NavigationStack` for navigation. I created `DetailViewModel` for `DetailView` and add it as `@StateObject` and also add it as `environmentObject` for `DetailView` subviews. All good as expected but if I present/show [PhotosPicker](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/photospicker) and return back to `ContentView` I can see that `DetailViewModel` isn't deinit. Is it memory leak? How can we fix/avoid this? Thanks.

Below I added code from the simple project also for convenience you can have a have look on [GitHub](https://github.com/alexanderkhitev/StateObjectForStackOverflowDemo)

**ContentView:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            let route = Route.detail
            NavigationLink("Show Detail", value: route)
                .navigationDestination(for: Route.self) { route in
                    switch route {
                    case .detail:
                        DetailView()
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

**Route:**

```
enum Route: Hashable {
    case detail
}
```

**DetailView:**

```
import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI

struct DetailView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = DetailViewModel()
    // just for test
    @State private var photoPickerPresented = false
    @State private var selectedPickerItem: PhotosPickerItem?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                photoPickerPresented.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Show Photo Picker")
            }
        }
        .photosPicker(isPresented: $photoPickerPresented, selection: $selectedPickerItem)
        .environmentObject(viewModel)
    }
}
```

**DetailViewModel:**

```
class DetailViewModel: ObservableObject {
    init() {
        debugPrint("DetailViewModel init")
    }

    deinit {
        debugPrint("DetailViewModel deinit")
    }
}
```

Comment: why would you want a view model object in SwiftUI in the first place? The View struct is already the model for the UIViews it generates.

Comment: I do some tests/experiments with SwiftUI and just try to understand this behavior (find information about it)

Comment: I had the same problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71674556/deinit-not-called-when-using-uiimagepickercontroller-in-swiftui. Do you have a solution?

Comment: Hey @J.Doe! Not for now. this is a very interesting issue